# Guardar Spinner dentro de una base de datos SQLite y mostrarlo después?

Tags: android, android-studio, base-de-datos, sqlite, android-sqlite

Tengo una base de datos ya creada y la cual se muestra en un Recyclerview con valores como Id, Nombre y Telefono y quiero colocar un spinner el cual me deje colocar una serie de valores, como puedo hacer para que cuando le de click en un valor del spinner se guarde dicho valor en SQLite y despues cuando vuelva a entrar a la actividad me muestre el valor guardado, agradezco toda la ayuda que me puedas brindar. Gracias.

Este es mi Maganer:

```
public class DataBaseManager {

    public static final String TABLA_PEDIDO = "pedido";
    public static final String CREAR_TABLA_PEDIDO = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLA_PEDIDO + " (" +
            "Id integer," +    
            "cantidad text," + //Este es espacio para asignarle el valor del spinner
            "Nombre text," +    
            "Descripcion text," +
            "precio integer)";   

    private DbHelper helper;
    private SQLiteDatabase db;

    public DataBaseManager(Context context) {
        helper = new DbHelper(context);
        db = helper.getWritableDatabase();
        db = helper.getReadableDatabase();
    }

    public void cerrar() {
        if (db.isOpen())
            db.close();
    }

    private ContentValues generarContentValues (int Id, String cantidad, String Nombre, String Descripcion, int Precio)
    {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put("Id", Id);
        cv.put("cantidad", cantidad);
        cv.put("Nombre", Nombre);
        cv.put("Descripcion", Descripcion);
        cv.put("Precio", Precio);
        return cv;
    }

    public void insertar(int Id, String cantidad, String Nombre, String Descripcion, int Precio) {
        db.insert(TABLA_PEDIDO, null, generarContentValues(Id, cantidad, Nombre, Descripcion, Precio));
    }

    public void modificarValor (int Id, String nuevacantidad, String Nombre, String Descripcion, int Precio){

   SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getWritableDatabase();

   if (db != null){

   db.update(TABLA_PEDIDO, generarContentValues(Id, nuevacantidad, Nombre, Descripcion, Precio), "pysId=?", new String[]{String.valueOf(pysId)});
            db.close();
        }
    }

public List<Producto> getPedidoList() {

  List<Producto> pedido = new ArrayList<Producto>();
  String seleccion = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLA_PEDIDO;
  SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getReadableDatabase();
  Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(seleccion, null);

  if (cursor.moveToFirst()){
            do {
                pedido.add(new Producto(cursor.getInt(0),cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2), cursor.getString(3), cursor.getInt(4)));
            }while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        cursor.close();
        db.close();

        return pedido;
    }

    public void openDB (){
        try {
            db = helper.getWritableDatabase();
            db = helper.getReadableDatabase();
        }catch (SQLException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Este es mi Helper:

```js
public class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final String DB_NOMBRE = "juan.sqlite";
    private static final int VERSION = 1;

    public DbHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DB_NOMBRE, null, VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        //crear tabla pedido
        try {
            db.execSQL(DataBaseManager.CREAR_TABLA_PEDIDO);

        }catch (SQLException e)
        {e.getMessage();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS" + DataBaseManager.TABLA_PEDIDO);
        onCreate(db);
    }
}
```

Y este es mi adaptador:

```js
public class ProductoAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ProductoAdapter.ProductoViewHolder> {
    //Cargando la imagen y el contexto
    Context mainContext;
    DataBaseManager db;

    int Id, Precio;
    String Cantidades, nuevaCantidad, Nombre, Descripcion;

    //Para almacenar una lista de todos los Clientes
    List<Producto> items;
    int selectedPos;

    public ProductoAdapter(List<Producto> items, Context contexto) {
        super();
        this.items = items;
        this.mainContext = contexto;
    }

    @Override
    public ProductoViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.mostrar_pedido, parent, false);
        ProductoViewHolder pHolder = new ProductoViewHolder(v);
        return pHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ProductoViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {
        Producto item = items.get(position);
   viewHolder.txtpysId.setText(String.valueOf(item.getId()));
   viewHolder.txtnombre.setText(item.getNombre());
   viewHolder.txtdescrip.setText(item.getDescripcion());
   viewHolder.txtprecio.setText(String.valueOf(item.getPrecio()));
   viewHolder.txtcant.setAdapter(a());

   viewHolder.txtcant.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                nuevaCantidad = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();

            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });
    }

private SpinnerAdapter a() {

        String[] pedido = new String[]{"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"};

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(mainContext,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, pedido);

        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

        return adapter;
}

public void modificarValor (int Id, String nuevaCantidad, String Nombre, String Descripcion, int Precio){
        DataBaseManager dbManager = new DataBaseManager(mainContext);
        dbManager.modificarValor(Id, nuevaCantidad, Nombre, Descripcion, Precion);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
        return items.size();
}

class ProductoViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

        // Campos respectivos de un item
        public TextView txtId;
        public TextView txtnombre;
        public TextView txtdescrip;
        public TextView txtprecio;
        Spinner txtcant;

        public ProductoViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            txtId = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.Id);
            txtnombre = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txtNombre);
            txtdescrip = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txtVDescripcion);
            txtprecio = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.precio);
            txtcant = (Spinner) v.findViewById(R.id.cantidad);

        }
    }
}
```

Esta es la actividad.

```js
public class Pedidos extends AppCompatActivity implements OnItemSelectedListener {

    Spinner spinner;

    Context mainContext;
    private DataBaseManager managerPedidos;
    private RecyclerView recycler;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager lManager;
    private List<Producto> listaItemsCursos;
    private int id_pedido;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_pedidos);
        MultiDex.install(this);

        managerPedidos = new DataBaseManager(this);
        listaItemsCursos = managerPedidos.getPedidoList();

        // Obtener el Recycler
        recycler = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.pedidos);
        recycler.setHasFixedSize(true);

        // Usar un administrador para LinearLayout
        lManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        recycler.setLayoutManager(lManager);

        // Crear un nuevo adaptador
        ProductoAdapter adapter = new ProductoAdapter(listaItemsCursos, this);
        recycler.setAdapter(adapter);

        recycler.addOnScrollListener(rVOnScrollListener);
        recycler.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    }
}
```

No se como guardar el spinner en el SQLite y que despues cuando vuelva a ingresar a esa actividad me muestre el spinner seleccionado, actualmente me sigue mostrando el primero por defecto.

Agradezco todos los que me puedan ayudar. Gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Para poder hacer lo que necesitas, una vez que guardes los valores en la base de datos y vuelvas a entrar a la activity. Haz un select de esos valores guardados por ejemplo mi spinner tiene :

```
Chile
Peru
Mexico
```

Y en mi base de datos guardo mi valor `Chile`, entonces quiero que cuando vuelva a cargar la vista este valor se marque por defecto.

```
//Este valor debería saber el que guardaste en la base de datos.

String valorSeleccionado = "Chile";
ArrayAdapter myAdaptador = (ArrayAdapter) miSpinner.getAdapter();

//obtenemos la posición 

int spinnerPosition = myAdaptador.getPosition(valorSeleccionado);

//y damos finalmente la posicion que queremos dejar seleccionada

miSpinner.setSelection(spinnerPosition);
```

Answer (score 0):

La manera más directa sería utilizar [Shared Preferences](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) para guardar la posición cada vez que se selecciona un valor en el spinner. Entonces cuando vuelves a iniciar la actividad simplemente seteas esa posicion usando [setSelection(posicion)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsSpinner.html#setSelection(int,%20boolean)).

Comment: Hola Jirungary muchas gracias por tu respuesta.
Como puedes observar estoy manejando una base de datos SQLite en la cual estoy guardando toda la información, pero a la hora de volver a ingresar a la actividad me aparece la información y solo me hace falta es el valor del Spinner los demás valores si me los esta mostrando como debe ser.
No se cual sería el código apropiado para que el spinner me trajera dicha información de la base de datos SQLite.
O como seria el mejor metodo para mi caso.
Te agradezco toda la ayuda que me puedas brindar.